# Strange results for NMOS component in LTSpice

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

I am testing the I V curve of the mosfet in LTSpice

I get strange results when the standard 'NMOS' componant is reverse biased, (when the source is more positive than the drain) I get tera-amps flowing into the drain and mili-amps out of the source, no current into the gate.

Is this because the model for the MOSFET is incomplete and only works for the positive I V quadrant, or could there some kind of bug in the software?

Comment: Can you share the schematic and the model?

Comment: I would be tricky to send a photo right now. I have connected the drain to a voltage supply ramped from -10 to +10, the gate to +2v, the source to ground.

Comment: Reversing the drain to source biasing will (as noted) turn on the body diode. What you will see depends on whether there is any limiting resistance. Use the built-in circuit editor to add the same schematic and update the question, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you observe the behaviour of the body diode that gets forward biased.

Comment: Maybe I should have a go with the other MOSFET that has the body as a separate terminal. Even so the model must not be complete for reverse basis, I should not be getting tera-amps or more current flowing in than is flowing out.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Sometimes the fourth terminal is connected to some global node, so the current is leaving through that node and you can't probe it. It would be interesting to know which simulator you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this behavior because you are forward biasing the body diode AND the power source that you are using for the -10V to +10V ramp has been left set to its default source resistance of 0 ohms.

No bug here. Put a diode forward biased across a power supply that can deliver unlimited current at whatever voltage that you have chosen and the it will do its best to comply.

Now of course there is no practical power supply that can really do that so set the Rser (parasitic Series Resistance) if the supply and things become a whole lot more realistic. I tried your experiment with Rser = 0.25 ohms and saw a current more like 40A. So if you put the N-FET across something like a high energy 12V car battery you could still expect it to blow out.

Keep in mind that the generic model for the N-FET models the body diode as an ideal diode with no bulk series resistance. Select a model for some actual component and you should see a difference. In my experience some of the N-FET models have the body diode setup with some effective series resistance and some have ideal diode behavior of 0ohm series resistance.